# Silex and Ajax communication issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, silex

I have an problem with ajax communication with Silex.
So, I created an JS file with Ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    async: 'true',
    url: "/get-taxonomy-details",
    success: function(html){
        if(html != '') {
            console.log(html);
        }
    },
    error: function(x,e){
        console.log('Ajax', e, x);
    }
});
```

Then in already existing Silex controller inside of "connect(Application $app)" I added a route like this:

```
$factory->post('/get-taxonomy-details', function() {
  return 'ok';
});
```

I get an error that the route is not found:

```
POST http://www.my_site.dev/get-taxonomy-details 404 (Not Found)
```

This is just an general example what I want to achieve.
Since I'm new in Silex I'm not sure what I am missing?

I was reading Silex doc and I have tried with GET too.
[Silex DOC](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/usage.html)

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us where the $factory comes from? Did you try a get route? Is it working without appending the index.php file in the route?

Comment: Using inspect element in the network tab, do the ajax call and see where the URL is pointing. Is really this your structure? http://www.my_site.dev/get-taxonomy-details